# Failed opening required

Tags: php

**Error**
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/demohab/public_html/mailout/admin/com/lib/mc9uowrh329xzx.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/demohab/public_html/mailout/admin/com/init.php on line 57

**CODE**(42-59)

```
function __iem_autoload_function($className)
{
    // faster than calling require_once
    // also, if the class already exists, then we don't even need to autoload the file
    if (class_exists($className)) {
        return;
    }

    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/' . str_replace('_', '/', $className);

    // the .class.php naming convention is now deprecated, but since most files still use it
    // so it is put first to improve performance
    if (is_readable($path . '.class.php')) {
        require $path . '.class.php';
    } else {
        require $path . '.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the path correct? Does the file actually exist?

Comment: If the file exists, does user under whom PHP is running have permissions to read that file?

Comment: The file is not virtually present. Also i had assigned 755

Answer (score 2):

The problem was because of wrong file permission given as 777.
I rectified by reinstalling fresh one on linux server.

Answer (score 0):

The path you are trying to open, does not exist.

This can have multiple reasons, the most common are:

1. The file doesn't exist (doh!).
2. Your include path isn't correct.

Comment: Those two reasons are really the same thing :p

Comment: The file is created dynamically i guess! so may i know how to handle such situation?

Comment: Do you see **any** files in that directory? Do you have the correct permissions to write files? Perhaps the errors aren't logged?

Comment: I agree here with Wesley, perhaps directory permissions are wrong

Comment: I see few files in that directory. 755 is file permission how to check error logs? i use cpanel and errors are logged there

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to open a file (require it into your code) mc9uowrh329xzx.php and it does not exist at the location of '/home/demohab/public_html/mailout/admin/com/lib/'

Comment: I do agree it. but the same code is running good in another shared hosting but when i host in VPS it shows error. i guess the file mc9uowrh329xzx.php is created dynamically. so i'm unable to crosscheck too, the path.